# SQL query find rows with related dates

Tags: sql, date, rows, exists, combiners

*push*
I have a query in firbird sql, which shows me the last jobs from the employees. It could be possible, that a job is shown multiple, because the employee could be often by one customer.

I have a query like:

```
**employee** - **from** - **till** - **Customer**
Ronaldo - 2017-01-01 - 2017-03-31 - Real Madrid
Ronaldo - 2017-04-01 - 2017-05-20 - Real Madrid
Ronaldo - 2017-05-25 - 2017-06-10 - Barcelona
Ronaldo - 2017-06-13 - 2017-12-31 - Real Madrid
```

**Now, my result should be like that:**

```
Ronaldo - 2017-01-01 - 2017-05-20 - Real Madrid
Ronaldo - 2017-05-25 - 2017-06-10 - Barcelona
```

That means, I do not want to have the row which is up to date and related rows combine with the first from and the last till, if the next from is not older then 7 days from the first till - otherwhise I want to have shown both.

**My SQL now is:**

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
 WITH TB_LA as
    (
    SELECT EP.PERSONALNR, max(EP.DATUMVON) as DATUMVON
    FROM EINSPERS EP, AUFTRAG A
    WHERE EP.PERSONALNR = 10337 AND EP.BERUFSCHL is not null AND EP.DATUMVON 

, TB_A as 
    (
    SELECT EP.PERSONALNR, EP.AUFTRAGNR, EP.DATUMVON, EP.DATUMBIS, K.KUNDENNR, 1 as PARM
    FROM EINSPERS EP, TB_LA, AUFTRAG A, KUNDEN K
    WHERE EP.BERUFSCHL is not null AND EP.DATUMVON <= TIMESTAMP 'TODAY' AND TB_LA.PERSONALNR = EP.PERSONALNR AND TB_LA.DATUMVON = EP.DATUMVON AND EP.AUFTRAGNR = A.AUFTRAGNR AND A.KUNDENNR = K.KUNDENNR
    )
, TB_H as
    (
    SELECT EP.PERSONALNR, EP.AUFTRAGNR, EP.DATUMVON, EP.DATUMBIS, K.KUNDENNR, K.KUNDNAME, K.DISPONENT as DISPOKU, P.DISPONENT AS DISPOMA
    FROM EINSPERS EP
    INNER JOIN AUFTRAG A ON EP.AUFTRAGNR = A.AUFTRAGNR
    INNER JOIN KUNDEN K ON A.KUNDENNR = K.KUNDENNR
    INNER JOIN TB_LA ON TB_LA.PERSONALNR = EP.PERSONALNR
    INNER JOIN PERSONAL P ON P.PERSONALNR = EP.PERSONALNR
    LEFT JOIN TB_A ON TB_A.PERSONALNR = EP.PERSONALNR AND TB_A.KUNDENNR = K.KUNDENNR AND (TB_A.DATUMVON >= (EP.DATUMBIS-14) or TB_A.DATUMVON = EP.DATUMVON)
    WHERE EP.BERUFSCHL is not null AND EP.DATUMVON <= TIMESTAMP 'TODAY' AND EP.DATUMBIS >= TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31' AND CASE WHEN K.KUNDENNR = TB_A.KUNDENNR THEN 1 ELSE NULL END is null AND TB_A.PARM is null
    )
SELECT * FROM TB_H
)
```

my result is:

```
employee   from    till    customer
10337   30.01.2017  31.01.2017  120495
10337   14.02.2017  19.02.2017  117769
10337   20.02.2017  20.02.2017  127507
10337   21.02.2017  05.03.2017  127507
10337   06.03.2017  12.03.2017  117769
```

and at least I want to have the following result:

```
employee    from    till    customer
10337   30.01.2017  31.01.2017  120495
10337   14.02.2017  19.02.2017  117769
10337   20.02.2017  05.03.2017  127507
10337   06.03.2017  12.03.2017  117769
```

How can I do the last step? I have no idea to solve my problem :-(

add: it is possible to do this in ms sql or firebird sql, no matter which way, but I prefer firebird sql.

thank you!

Comment: Sorry, if I am missing the point : 
`Group by employee, max(from), max(till), customer`

Comment: @Yasuu Cannot use an aggregate function in a GROUP BY clause.. if I only add this in having clause, it does not solve the problem. I do not define the period of the 7 days.. :-(